# Unix/Linux Bash Scripting: sed doesn't respect spaces

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to develop a bash script which will be replacing/appending some lines in configuration files. I'm having an issue where sed isn't respecting spaces in my replaced line. This is what I've setup:

```
sedkey="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"
sednew="<Listener\ className=\"org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener\"\ rmiRegistryPortPlatform=\"7050\"\ rmiServerPortPlatform=\"7051\"\ \/\>"

sed -e "/"$sedkey"/a\\
"$sednew"" server-wc.xml
```

But when I run the script containing this, I get this:

```
sed: can't read className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"\: No such file or directory
sed: can't read rmiRegistryPortPlatform="7050"\: No such file or directory
sed: can't read rmiServerPortPlatform="7051"\: No such file or directory
sed: can't read \/\>: No such file or directory
```

While it adds the less than sign and "Listener" perfectly fine.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `sed  '/'"$sedkey"'/a\'"$sednew" server-wc.xml`... the double quotes in `sednew` is conflicting with outer double quotes of your sed command

Comment: That was perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: or perhaps not, the spaces were causing issue... see @that other guy's answer...

Comment: @that other guy solves your immediate problem; you still have the problem that you can't pass parameters to a `sed` script, you can only build a dynamic `sed` script. This means you are responsible for making sure the resulting script is what you intended. `foo="a/b"; sed "s/$foo//" ...` won't delete occurances of `a/b`; the resulting command is `sed "s/a/b//" ...`, which will produce an error in `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Always quoting variables and command expansions is good practice, but blindly putting quotes left and right of them is not.

In this case, the quotes around the expansion are unquoting it, because the left quote is terminating an existing double quoted string, while the right quote starts a new one. Example:

```
echo "You enter "$HOSTNAME". You can smell the wumpus."
     |----------|         |---------------------------|
        Quoted   No quotes           Quoted
```

In other words, you should just be using:

```
sed -e "/$sedkey/a\\
$sednew" server-wc.xml
```

---

[ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically points this out. This info was copied from [its wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2027). Also consider using an XML tool like `xmlstarlet` instead of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes instead of double quotes in the sed command to remove conflict with double quotes in variable, so that the sed command looks like:

```
sed '/'"$sedkey"'/a\'"$sednew" server-wc.xml
```

Thank you Sundeep!